# Gmail account was deleted

Tags: gmail, account-management

I created a second Gmail account, for my business, which I thought I created in a new Google account. It was deleted.

In the meantime I had nice business cards made up with that username and I do not want to have to redo my cards. I tried to open a new account but it would not accept the username saying it was already spoken for.

That was my name. No one else would have had it. What can I do to recover my account or start a new one with the username I gave it. If I have to cancel my personal Gmail acct I will do that.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you go through the Account Recovery wizard? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDMQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Frecovery%2F&ei=2AOBUI7UFcSC4gSihYG4DQ&usg=AFQjCNFVI7rdxuQjzu-2DudhY__g3mPf8w&sig2=qKXer9EYO6OCon5HrTLbCg&cad=rja

Answer (score 2):

You can try recovering it via the Google Account recovery page: https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/?&hl=en&rd=2

This only works for a limited amount of time according to [the help article](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=67422):

> Google Accounts can only be recovered within a short period of time
>   after deletion. If you received an error message stating “This account
>   was deleted and is no longer recoverable,” the account has been
>   deleted for too long and cannot be restored by our support team.
>
> Some common reasons people see this message include:
>
> - Your account was disabled for perceived spamming and, because you did
>     not sign in to verify it, it was deleted. You never signed in to
>     verify your identity. After some time, your account was deleted as it
>     was deemed an abusive account.
> - You intended to delete a certain product from your account but
>     accidentally deleted the entire Google Account.
> - You never owned this account but it was deleted by the true owner.

Comment: I did all that. I even recovered it within the short time but then it disappeared again.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "Disappeared"